# wp_schedule_event is planned but function not firing

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, content-management-system

I have some trouble with the wp_schedule_event function and I was not able to find any solution here so far. 
The event is triggert, atleast I see the next planned when calling `wp_next_scheduled( 'update_expired_events_hourly' )`, but when the time is reached, nothing is happening.
Also the function is working fine when I call it manually. I tried to fire the event by calling /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron, but that had no effect either.

The following code is in my themes functions.php

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Thank you in advance!

```
add_action( 'wp', 'expired_activation' );
add_action( 'update_expired_events_hourly', 'update_expired_events' );



function expired_activation(){
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'update_expired_events_hourly' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'update_expired_events_hourly');
    }
}

function update_expired_events(){
    // events query
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'espresso_events',
        'post_status'       => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash'),
        'post_per_page'     => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'espresso_event_categories',
            'field'     => 'slug',  
            'terms'     => 'ee_exp', // the expired category slug
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
            ),
       )
    );
    $events = new WP_QUERY($args);
    $today = strtotime(current_time( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $gmt =0 )); // get current date

     if ( $events->have_posts() ){
         while ( $events->have_posts() ){
            $events->the_post();

            //get event end date
            $event_end = strtotime( espresso_event_end_date( 'Y-m-d', 'H:i:s', false, false ) ); // get event end date

            if( $event_end - (60*60*24) < $today ){
                wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ee_exp', 'espresso_event_categories', true); // Add post to expired category
            }

         }
     }
}
```

I forgot to mention, that define('DISABLE_WP_CRON'); is set to false in my config.php

---------------------- EDIT ----------------------
The code above is working. Apparently the only thing not working was firing the event via URL (/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron). Sorry for that and thx for your help!

Comment: Are you aware that it's not a server cron? It will not be triggered if no one visit your website. From [wp_schedule_event documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event): "The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed."

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this.

Comment: That's just a guess, but I'm not sure that the wp action is high enough to register crons. Usually I do the wp_schedule_event sraight in functions.php , without using any hook.

Comment: Thx, I will give this a try. But I think since the event is scheduled and just not firing when the time is reached, it is probably not the problem

Comment: Well the function is registered to the scheduled hook so it is supposed to trigger. Do you have any cache plugin? That could cause issues with crons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't disable wp_cron I suggest you use  wp_schedule_single_event it worked well for me

```
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 3600, 'update_expired_events_hourly' );
```